# How to download applications from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, vlc

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10, my very first Linux desktop. I want to download and install an application (VLC media player) from the Software Center. When I clicked the download button, a pop-up asked me to:

"This link needs to be opened with an application"

It sounds strange to me and I don't know what to do.

Could any guru tell me the proper way to get software online and install them.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is unsupported. You need to upgrade to 14.04.1 - run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simpler to install packages via command line

```
 sudo apt-get install PACKAGE-NAME
```

Where `PACKAGE-NAME` is the name of a available package - you can search for packages [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), or by running `sudo apt-cache search SEARCH-TERM`

In this case it would be `sudo apt-get install vlc`. Once you have entered your password, it should search for available packages, and install them once you have confirmed it can.

It is worth noting that [Ubuntu 13.10 is now End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life) - so you may need to follow the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) to able to install from the repositories. You can also downloaded the latest supported release (14.04(.1)) from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips. I find it works perfectly with command line. I installed it without problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can either open the software centre and search for VLC and install it (you will need to enter you password) or you can follow [this link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) and click the download button, it will automatically open VLC in the Software Centre.

You can also open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then copy and paste `sudo apt-get install vlc`. It will ask for you password, but you won't be able to see it typing - don't worry, it is still registering your key presses. Press enter when you have typed it.